# Comparison of clustering methods for mixed data

Tags: r, clustering

Sorry if the question is not suitable for this site. If so, I will remove it.

Simply, I am looking for reviews and comparisons between clustering methods which could be used for mixed data "continuous and discrete" and, if possible, their efficiency in R.

Articles, previous questions on stack overflow, or even blogs because I don't find a general review and comparison.

Comment: Hi Jean, welcome to Stats SE. Have you already looked into a textbook, such as Charu C. Aggarwal's Data Mining? The questions seems a bit broad as it stands and I feel for a good overview it would be best to turn to a handbook.

Answer (score 0):

See here:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/insr.12274
Not sure whether this is OpenAcess but I think they have a preprint pdf for free on ResearchGate.